# Multiple Functions Into One

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dom-traversal

I am trying to take these functions and combine them into one:

```
$(".a h3").click(function() {
   $(".a .collapse-this").slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".b h3").click(function() {
   $(".b .collapse-this").slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".c h3").click(function() {
   $(".c .collapse-this").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Something like this, but this causes everything to collapse, would like it to open one at a time:

```
$(".repeatingClass h3").click(function() {
      $(".collapse-this").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I have searched for a solution and came across using `$(this)` but I am a little stuck. So hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Please provide your markup structure for the elements in question.

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample of the HTML structure. The proper method of DOM selection from a given point depends on the structure you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell without knowing your markup, but you should give a common class for your `.a`, `.b` etc. elements. Then you could use:

```
$(".repeatingClass h3").click(function() {
     $(".collapse-this", $(this).closest('.repeatingClass')).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will find the first parent that matches the selector (`.repeatingClass`), and then I'm using it as the [context](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery) of the `.collapse-this` lookup. This means that it will search only in the given context, and its equivalent to `$(this).closest('.repeatingClass').find('.collapse-this')`.

[jsFiddle Demo to see I'm not lying ;)](http://jsfiddle.net/UgBxz/)

Comment: Since (as you stated) using the context argument is equivalent to `$(this).closest('.repeatingClass').find('.collapse-this')`, why not just use that? It's faster, and reads *so* much more cleanly.

Comment: @patrick For some reason the context reads more cleanly to me, but nowadays I'm switching to using `.find()`. When you make a habit of something, it's not easy to switch, that's why I wrote the code with context first. To sum up, you're right.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my *"reads so much more cleanly"* comment wasn't written to be as subjective as it ought to have been. It's all in the eye of the beholder! :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".a, .b, .c")
.addClass('repeatingClass')
.find('h3')
.click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.repeatingClass').find('.collapse-this').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: +1 But using `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a crack at it:

```
$(".repeatingClass h3").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".repeatingClass").find('.collapse-this').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The `closest` call finds the nearest parent of the element that satisfies the selector, in this case .repeatingClass

Comment: He wants to toggle `.collapse-this`.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the data- attributes to store references to other HTML on the page. So I'd set up the HTML as:

```
<h3 data-panel-id="panel1">blah blah</h3>
<h3 data-panel-id="panel2">blah blah</h3>
<h3 data-panel-id="panel3">blah blah</h3>
```

Then you can write this as your jQuery:

```
$('h3').click(function(){
    var panelID = $(this).data('panelId');
    $('#'+panelID).slideToggle("slow");
})
```

Comment: …why? It's a child of the panel. The element shouldn't need to declare the ID of its parent in an attribute.

Keeping other IDs in attributes makes sense only when the HTML structure doesn't already make it obvious what we're talking about.

Comment: Impossible to know/say without seeing the HTML. The above is useful when when one element has to interact with another independent of any particular parent/child relation.

Comment: @DA: though the question is unclear, this much *is* knowable. A click on `.a h3` triggers an animation on `.a .collapse-this`. The two elements are definitely both children of the parent we're interested in.

Comment: They MAY be siblings. But they just as likely may NOT be. The fact that they both share a class doesn't mean anything in and of itself.

Comment: @Matchu: They're not necessarily children. All we know is that they're descendants of the same ancestor, assuming there's only one `.a` element on the page.

Comment: example: `<div class="a"><h3>Hello</h3></div><div class="monkey"><div class="a"><div class="cow"><div class="collapse-this">Hi Again</div></div></div></div>`

Comment: "assuming there's only one `.a` element on the page" -> Exactly! It's can only be an assumption. There just as likely 10 `.a` elements as there is one. In fact, the reason to use classes is they can be reused throughout a document, so one could say that it's more likely that there is MORE than 1. (If there's only one, it should be an ID)

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way is to use multiple selectors, 
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score -2):

if the html is set up in such a way that you could get the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) element with jQuery.

```
$(".SharedClassName").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".collapse-this").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Comment: The question's HTML structure was unclear, but I think this ignores the `.collapse-this` child element.

Comment: @Matchu, note that **xanderer** substituted class names, i.e. `ShareSlideClassName`

Comment: @Jason, yeah, but, as I read it, `.collapse-this` is a child of the `h3`. He just steps up to the parent, and never goes down to the child.